# How to define the size of member vector in constructor of a class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, stdvector

I want to make a vector first without a size ( `vector<int> times`)  and  I want to define its *size* later in a constructor of a  class ( `times(size)` ).

I can do it by using the initializer list as you see below

```
class A (int size): times(size) {};
```

But my question is that why I can not do it in a constructor out of a class like the code below?

I mean why the code below is wrong?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int size);
private:
    std::vector<int> line;
};

A::A(int size)
{
    line(size);// here I got the error
}
```

`line(size)` make an error

Comment: The version you have written looks like you are trying to call a function called `line` with a single parameter `size`. Not surprisingly the compiler gets confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the member function [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) for that

```
A::A(int size)
{
    line.resize(size);
}
```

---

The member `line` will be default constructed(i.e. `std::vector<int> line{}`) before reaching the body of the constructor. And hence writing `line(size);` makes no sense, hence
the compiler error.

Much better would be using the [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), which will help
to construct the vector from the size passed and initialize with `0` 's, before reaching the constructor body.

```
A(int size) : line(size) {}
```

It uses the following constructor of  [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

```
explicit vector( size_type count );   // (since C++11)(until C++14)
explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); // (since C++14)
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to either use an [initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
A::A(int size) : line(size)
{ }
```

or assign a [new value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to `line`:

```
A::A(int size)
{
  this->line = std::vector(size);
}
```

These two options will insert `size` elements into the vector. So the vector will be filled with default values. If you only want to make sure there is enough space to insert that many elements on a later point in time use [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to increase capacity of the already constructed vector:

```
A::A(int size)
{
  this->line.reserve(size);
}
```

### Clarification

If you use the first or second option `line.size()` and `line.capacity()` will be equal `size`, because default elements have been inserted into the vector.
With the third option, no default elements will be inserted, so `line.size()` will be 0 and `line.capacity()` is `size`.

Comment: Please note that `reserve` does something very different to the other 2 options! `resize` may be more appropriate?

Comment: I edited my answer but feel free to edit it, if I was not clear enough :)

Answer (score 2):

The code is wrong because you attempted to re-initialize in the body of your constructor a vector that was already initialized to size 0.

Change your constructor code to use the initializer list

```cpp
A::A(int size)
  : line(size)
{
}
```